# Binding in page navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, variables, binding

I have another question with windows phone 7 dev. I'm creating listbox with items and one textblock, which is something like link to another page. Each link will have another "page" variable value.

```
<TextBlock Tap="TextBlock_Tap" Foreground="#FF40AA2F" Text="View details">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <ec:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/details.xaml?page={Binding Index}" />

                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</TextBlock>
```

But it doesn't work with current value in targetpage, because Visual Studio taking it like normal string. How can I embed this binding in page variable? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using StringFormat:

```
<ec:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="{Binding Path=Index, StringFormat='/details.xaml?page={0}'}" />
```

Comment: debugger says that in place of zero is error: "Expected ' ". And in place after word "page" is expecting " } ". what's wrong ? Your idea is good but i dont know how make it work.

Comment: @ŁukaszWróblewski Can you try surrounding the StringFormat parameter with quotes? `TargetPage="{Binding Path=Index, StringFormat='/details.xaml?page={0}'}"`

Comment: I solved that problem in code-behind way. This is TextBlock_Tap:
 
Person data = (sender as TextBlock).DataContext as Person;
            ListBoxItem pressedItem = this.listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as ListBoxItem;
            if (pressedItem != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(data.Index);
            }

It's doing the same as I wanted in XAML way. But thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the navigation, not on a trigger but in the code behind of the MouseLeftButtonDown event of the Text Block and extract the target page from the current selection of the listbox.